# R-How to compare two dataframe and update list column value

Tags: r

I have two data frame dataframe 1, dataframe 2,How to compare  two dataframe column values against P.Name,Name,Q.Name and update same value and append different row of value. please check below Ex.

Data frame1

```
P.Name    Name      Q.Name                    values

Read     Mike        salseID                  list(value = "Y2TS", countofvalues = 1)

Write    jhon        Purchasedcust            list(value = "ANDERSON", countofvalues = 1)

write    jhon        shippingname             list(value = "Mikel", countofvalues = 5)

Read     peter       ordername                list(value = c("july", "mary", "petersonavail"), countofvalues = c(1, 2, 1))

Write    jack        deliveredadd             list(value = c("IICC PS LOL UY", "IICC UYY LOL UY"), countofvalues = c(2,1))
```

Dataframe 2

```
P.Name    Name      Q.Name                    values

Read     Mike        salseID                  list(value = "Y2TS", countofvalues = 1)

Write    jhon        Purchasedcust            list(value = "vjantony", countofvalues = 1)

write    jhon        CustaAddress             list(value = "Mikel", countofvalues = 5)

Read     peter       ordername                list(value = c("july", "mary", "parker"), countofvalues = c(1, 2, 1))
```

Expected data frame:

```
P.Name    Name      Q.Name                    values

 Read     Mike        salseID                  list(value = "Y2TS", countofvalues = 2)

 Write    jhon        Purchasedcust            list(value = c("ANDERSON","vjantony"), countofvalues = c(1,1))

 write    jhon        shippingname             list(value = "Mikel", countofvalues = 5)

 write    jhon        CustaAddress             list(value = "Mikel", countofvalues = 5)

 Read     peter       ordername                list(value = c("july", "mary", "petersonavail","parker"), countofvalues = c(2, 4, 1,1))

 Write    jack        deliveredadd             list(value = c("IICC PS LOL UY", "IICC UYY LOL UY"), countofvalues = c(2,1))
```

Data frame1 dput data.

```
structure(list(P.Name = c("Read", "Write", "Write", "Read", "Write"
), Name = c("Mike", "jhon", "jhon", "peter", "jack"), Q.Name = c("salseID", 
"Purchasedcust", "shippingname", "ordername", "deliveredadd"), 
    values = list(structure(list(value = "Y2TS", countofvalues = 1L), .Names = c("value", 
    "countofvalues"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(value = "ANDERSON", 
        countofvalues = 1L), .Names = c("value", "countofvalues"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    )), structure(list(value = "Mikel", countofvalues = 5L), .Names = c("value", 
    "countofvalues"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(value = c("july", "mary", 
    "petersonavail"), countofvalues = c(1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("value", 
    "countofvalues"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(value = c("IICC PS LOL UY", 
    "IICC UYY LOL UY"), countofvalues = c(2L, 1L)), .Names = c("value", 
    "countofvalues"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")))), .Names = c("P.Name", "Name", "Q.Name", 
"values"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data frame 2 dput data

```
structure(list(P.Name = c("Read", "Write", "Write", "Read"), 
    Name = c("Mike", "jhon", "jhon", "peter"), Q.Name = c("salseID", 
    "Purchasedcust", "CustaAddress", "ordername"), values = list(
        structure(list(value = "Y2TS", countofvalues = 1L), .Names = c("value", 
        "countofvalues"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
        "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(value = "vjantony", 
            countofvalues = 1L), .Names = c("value", "countofvalues"
        ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
        "data.frame")), structure(list(value = "Mikel", countofvalues = 5L), .Names = c("value", 
        "countofvalues"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
        "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(value = c("july", 
        "mary", "parker"), countofvalues = c(1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("value", 
        "countofvalues"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
        "tbl", "data.frame")))), .Names = c("P.Name", "Name", 
"Q.Name", "values"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: to compare two columns you can just do df1$col1==df2$col1 ... you will get TRUE or FALSE... but the second part of your question is really unclear.... what you mean with update the list? where those values in the list are coming from? Without further explanations it's difficult to help.. also you should show your code so far.. what did you already try?

Comment: @Thai, actually what's my  expectation is just take dataframe 2 row value  and compare dataframe 1 row value by P.Name,Name ,Q.Name  if P.Name,Name ,Q.Name  row  values are common means  we need to update list of value  otherwise need to add compared row. for ex: dataframe 1 first row and dataframe 2  first row values are common at same time list values are also common So  countofvalues =2.But second row P.Name,Name,Q.Name row values are  same but list value different so countofvalues = c(1,1)).

Comment: where is the dput from data2?

Comment: @jimbou, I have updated dput of data frame 2.please check.

Comment: @Jimbou,Thanks for you're response but my requirement is different can you please refer my Expected data frame above. I need to group P.Name,Name , Q.Name.if new row of value I need to append.

Comment: OK. but why you choose  for `Read-Mike- salseID-Y2TS` `value=2` and not `value=1`

Comment: simply adding countofvalues from dataframe 1 and dataframe 2 if  P.Name ,Name ,Q.Name values are same.

Comment: At the same time can u please ref second row of both data frame 1,dataframe 2 ,P.Name ,Name ,Q.Name values are same but values column value are different like "ANDERSON","vjantony" that's why countofvalues is 1,1.

Comment: @kannank see my edits. Should be correct.

Comment: @Jimbou,Thanks it has been worked as I expected .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse`/`dplyr` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
# remove NAs. Otherwise it will not work. Don't know if they are important. 
d1$values <- lapply(d1$values, function(x) x[!is.na(x[,1]),])
d2$values <- lapply(d2$values, function(x) x[!is.na(x[,1]),])

d1 %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  bind_rows(unnest(d2)) %>% 
  group_by(P.Name, Name, Q.Name, value) %>% 
  summarise(countofvalues=sum(countofvalues)) 
# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   P.Name, Name, Q.Name [?]
   P.Name  Name        Q.Name           value countofvalues
    <chr> <chr>         <chr>           <chr>         <int>
 1   Read  Mike       salseID            Y2TS             2
 2   Read peter     ordername            july             2
 3   Read peter     ordername            mary             4
 4   Read peter     ordername          parker             1
 5   Read peter     ordername   petersonavail             1
 6  Write  jack  deliveredadd  IICC PS LOL UY             2
 7  Write  jack  deliveredadd IICC UYY LOL UY             1
 8  Write  jhon  CustaAddress           Mikel             5
 9  Write  jhon Purchasedcust        ANDERSON             1
10  Write  jhon Purchasedcust        vjantony             1
11  Write  jhon  shippingname           Mikel             5
```

Then you can nest the last columns using `nest()`

```
d1 %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  bind_rows(unnest(d2)) %>% 
  group_by(P.Name, Name, Q.Name, value) %>% 
  summarise(countofvalues=sum(countofvalues)) %>% 
  nest(.key = "values")
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  P.Name  Name        Q.Name           values
   <chr> <chr>         <chr>           <list>
1   Read  Mike       salseID <tibble [1 x 2]>
2   Read peter     ordername <tibble [4 x 2]>
3  Write  jack  deliveredadd <tibble [2 x 2]>
4  Write  jhon  CustaAddress <tibble [1 x 2]>
5  Write  jhon Purchasedcust <tibble [2 x 2]>
6  Write  jhon  shippingname <tibble [1 x 2]>
```